# Error deploying on Android, caused by PushNotification plugin

Tags: gluon

Error when trying to deploy on Android, IOS works fine.
The error started when I added the PushNotification plugin.

:apkDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':apkDebug'.

  > com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK LICENSE
  >       File 1: /Users/antoniopereira/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gms/google-services/3.0.0/ee538ce9cf4148485e43017c5542202b8c78ff8e/google-services-3.0.0.jar
  >       File 2: /Users/antoniopereira/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.gms/google-services/3.0.0/ee538ce9cf4148485e43017c5542202b8c78ff8e/google-services-3.0.0.jar
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the simple and already made solution of excludes:

packagingOptions {

```
        exclude 'LICENSE'

    }
```